# SQL Query Optimization help

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

my foundation on SQL is pretty weak so I hope you could bear with me. I have three tables: contents, categories, and categorization. The setup was chosen since some content will belong to one or more categories.

I want to fetch contents and its corresponding categories.

This is an overly-simplified version of the current script, without error-checking routines:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM contents WHERE contents.foo = 'bar'"
$resource = mysql_query($q);
$categoryFilter = array();

$q2 = "SELECT * FROM categorization WHERE ";
while($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
{
    $categoryFilter[] = "content_id='" . $content["id"] . "'";
}

if(count($categoryFilter))
{
    $q2 .= implode(" OR ", $categoryFilter);
    mysql_query($q2);
}
```

That's the gist of it. I hope you get what I am trying to do. I don't know if I can actually use JOINS the `content_id` may be present in multiple rows in `categorization`. So what I did was to simply append multiple `OR`'s, trying to fetch items one by one. I really would not like to use multiple queries in this scenario.  I hope anyone could suggest an approach

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One query should be enough to fetch data from all three tables:

```sql
SELECT categories.category_id #, other fields
FROM contents
INNER JOIN categorization ON contents.content_id = categorization.content_id
INNER JOIN categories ON categorization.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE contents.content_id = 1 # AND other filters
```

Tweak the columns in the `SELECT` clause and/or conditions in `WHERE` clause according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The reason that I might not want to use JOINS is that one content may belong in 5 categories or more. I am returning a lot of data from the `content` table because I really need them. One column is actually data from a rich text (WYSIWYG) editor. So you can expect at least 1kb for that column. I don't want JOINS to duplicate those columns. All I need is the category IDs.

Comment: @Ronlando: in that case I'd rather use two queries: one to select necessary columns from content table; the other to select just the category_id and category_name (the above one). If you do not specify the *lots_of_data* column in the select clause, the query won't return it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can do this in one sql statement

```sql
SELECT *
FROM contents t1 
JOIN categorization t2
WHERE t1.content_id = t2.content_id AND t1.foo = 'bar'
```

Also ensure that content_id is indexed both in 'content' and 'categorization'. You may find it worthwhile indexing 'foo' aswell, but it depends on how you are actually searching.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same thing as in your example:

```
$q = "
    SELECT *
    FROM
        contents c
        categorization ctg ON ctg.content_id = c.id
    WHERE c.foo = 'bar'
";

$result = mysql_query($q);
```